# Why Apache Spark take function not parallel?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark

Reading Apache Spark guide at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html it states :

[image]

Why is take function not run in parallel? What are the difficulties in implementing this type of function in parallel ? Is it something to do with fact that in order to take first n elements of RDD it is required to traverse entire RDD ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, while `take` is not entirely parallel, it's not entirely sequential either.

For example let's say you `take(200)`, and each partition has 10 elements. `take` will first fetch partition 0 and see that it has 10 elements. It assumes that it would need 20 such partitions to get 200 elements. But it's better to ask for a bit more in a parallel request. So it wants 30 partitions, and it already has 1. So it fetches partitions 1 to 29 next, *in parallel*. This will likely be the last step. If it's very unlucky, and does not find a total of 200 elements, it will again make an estimate and request another batch in parallel.

Check out the code, it's well documented:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1049

I think the documentation is wrong. Local calculation only happens when a single partition is required. This is the case in the first pass (fetching partition 0), but typically not the case in later passes.

Comment: thanks, when you say its not "entirely" parallel. Are you referring to fact that in comment for "take" function it states that "It works by first scanning one partition". So for 10 partitions, first partition will be scanned prior to other 9 partitions being scanned in parallel ?

Comment: Yes. But in the worst case it will go through the partitions entirely sequentially. For this the size of partitions has to be geometrically decreasing, though — quite unlikely in practice. In practice the partition sizes are typically uniform, so `take` will take 2 iterations, like you describe.

Comment: I've sent a pull request to fix the docs. (https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4533) I'll update the answer if it turns out I was mistaken.

Comment: Nicely explained. helped me !! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How would you implement it in parallel? Let's say you have 4 partitions and want to take first 5 elements. If you knew in advance the size of each partition, it would be easy: for example, if each partition has 3 elements driver asks partition 0 for all elements and it asks partition 1 for 2 elements. So the problem is that it *isn't* known how many elements each partition has.

Now, you could first calculate partition sizes, but this requires limiting the set of RDD transformations supported, calculating elements more than once, or some other tradeoff, and will generally need more communication overhead.

Comment: I just assumed parallel version would be implemented at some point in future as doc reads "currently not executed in parallel".

Comment: As I said, there can be tradeoffs to allow (at least some) parallelism. They just haven't decided which one to make (if any), as far as I understand.

Comment: Why not just take roughly equal number of rows from each partition in parallel? Take() doesn't guarantee that it uses up all of one partition before it moves onto the next, so why does it bother following this approach?

Comment: @max It does: "returns an array with the **first** _n_ elements".