# Do parquet files preserve the row order of Spark DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

When I save a Spark DataFrame as a parquet file then read it back, the rows of the resulting DataFrame are not the same as the original as shown in the session below. Is this a "feature" of DataFrames or of parquet files? What would be the best way to save a DataFrame in a row-order preserving manner?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,2)))
>>> pdf
          0         1
0  0.191519  0.622109
1  0.437728  0.785359
2  0.779976  0.272593
3  0.276464  0.801872
4  0.958139  0.875933
5  0.357817  0.500995
6  0.683463  0.712702
7  0.370251  0.561196
8  0.503083  0.013768
9  0.772827  0.882641
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)
>>> df.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+
|                  0|                   1|
+-------------------+--------------------+
| 0.1915194503788923|  0.6221087710398319|
| 0.4377277390071145|  0.7853585837137692|
| 0.7799758081188035|  0.2725926052826416|
| 0.2764642551430967|  0.8018721775350193|
| 0.9581393536837052|  0.8759326347420947|
|0.35781726995786667|  0.5009951255234587|
| 0.6834629351721363|  0.7127020269829002|
|0.37025075479039493|  0.5611961860656249|
| 0.5030831653078097|0.013768449590682241|
|  0.772826621612374|  0.8826411906361166|
+-------------------+--------------------+
>>> df.write.parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df2 = sqlContext.read.parquet('test.parquet')
>>> df2.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+
|                  0|                   1|
+-------------------+--------------------+
| 0.6834629351721363|  0.7127020269829002|
|0.37025075479039493|  0.5611961860656249|
| 0.5030831653078097|0.013768449590682241|
|  0.772826621612374|  0.8826411906361166|
| 0.7799758081188035|  0.2725926052826416|
| 0.2764642551430967|  0.8018721775350193|
| 0.1915194503788923|  0.6221087710398319|
| 0.4377277390071145|  0.7853585837137692|
| 0.9581393536837052|  0.8759326347420947|
|0.35781726995786667|  0.5009951255234587|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like it's the result of partitioning within Spark (as well as the implementation for `show()`). The function `show()` essentially wraps some pretty formatting around a call to `take()` and there is a good explanation as to how take works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436559/why-apache-spark-take-function-not-parallel). Since the initially read partitions may not be the same across both calls to `show()`, you will see different values.

Comment: So are you saying that, internally, parquet files preserve the order of the rows and it just so happened that the first partition read by `show()`/`take()` is wrong (which is a bit odd because parquet files should know the order of each chunk)? I also thought it might be related to `show()`/`take()` but only read the docs ("Prints the first n rows to the console") and not the source code.

Comment: @ianalis Yes, if you read [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#take), the documentation states that `take()` works first by "scanning _one_ partition", not limited to the first one. First `n` rows printed might refer to the first `n` rows found. Parquet should preserve row ordering within a file (i.e. if you were to point a Hive table at your files and query your data multiple times with the same command, you would see the same row ordering).

Comment: Thanks! Should this be considered a bug or should I submit a feature request?

Comment: @ianalis It would be a request.