# Pyspark dataframe: Repartitioning with an .orderBy that doesn't seem to orderBy

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Ok... Everything is going pretty good.  The last part of this script is to just get it in order, which I thought would be a fairly simple thing.

I'm doing a bunch of structural checks against their data, and all of that is working great.  The final segments of the script do these items in order:

1. Add Index (zipWithIndex) ['id']: It is specifically happening here since I want this column to be 1st position in the table.  This Works Great

```
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda r: pyspark.sql.Row(*r[0], r[1] + 1)).toDF(df.schema.add(pyspark.sql.types.StructField('id', pyspark.sql.types.LongType(), False)))
```

2. Repartition and .orderBy['id']: The orderBy is my issue

```
df = df.repartition(intNumPartitions).orderBy(pyspark.sql.functions.col('id'))
# Tried to also run an action right after the wide transformation to see if
# that would correct it.  It didn't, still have the same issue.
intRows = df.count()
```

3. Create data columns: Due to the nature of what this script is doing, the data is currently in a column: ['value'] with each row being an array collection of that rows column values.  Here it creates real columns and assigns the value to the new column, this also works great.

```
i = 0
for header in headerRows:
  df = df.withColumn(strHeader, pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace(pyspark.sql.functions.col('value').getItem(i), '^"|"$', ''))
i += 1
```

4. Drop column set(s)

```
df = df.drop('value')
```

6. .saveToTable

```
df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('mydb.mytable')
```

My issue is that the id is not in order.  it looks like each partition is sorting it within itself, but once the partitions come back together they are out of order.  I've spot-checked the table, and the row data itself looks great.  Take any row, and that row has the right data, it's just not in order.

But

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here...

Comment: How did you know they are out of order? Are they out of order when you re-read them in a separate operation?

Comment: select * from mydb.dbo.mytable.  'id' runs concurrent form 1-49, then jumps to 386, which runs concurrently to 433, and so on.  I don't see id = 50 until returned row #1926, which runs concurrently (id = 50-97) from rows 1926-1973

Comment: I suspect the partitions are not read in order

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020163/do-parquet-files-preserve-the-row-order-of-spark-dataframes

Comment: Wow. Ok.. facinating. Found out something. So I go into the parquet storage and see all of the parquets, if I read them one at a time in order... everything is in order.  It looks exactly what you're stating.  They literally aren't being read in order.  part-000 = 1-49, part-001 = 50-97, 3 = 98-145

Comment: Yes. Usually partitions are read in parallel, so they will be out of order.

Comment: Totally right... when I re-run the query, it's in another order