# Driver is unable to receive data from all executors for each partition

Tags: apache-spark

My knowledge with spark is at beginner level and I have created a program that will read all files from a directory and will apply some transformation and save the result into HDFS. I'm using Spark + Yarn.

IIUC, my job has just 1 stage and 5 tasks. Now since my directory has 22 files, I'm assuming there will be 22 partitions (assuming file size < block size), and each of these 5 tasks will be executed on each partition.

I supply 4 executors and I can see 4 executors are running on Spark UI.

**Question**

I expect driver to receive 10 records every time an executor is done applying all the tasks on a partition, but it doesn't do it. Instead, it looks like driver is printing the output from **one** partition only. What wrong I'm doing? Or Is my understanding wrong?

**Below is the code -**

It does nothing fancy; just applies a bunch of transformations and modify input rows and saves them into HDFS.

```
@Override
public void process() {
    // _inputDirectoryName has 22 files inside it.

    JavaRDD<String> linesRDD = _context.textFile(_inputDirectoryName);

    JavaRDD<StringBuilder> resultRDD = linesRDD
            .filter(row -> !AirlineDataUtils.isHeader(row))             
            .map(row -> AirlineDataUtils.getSelectResultsPerRow(row))
            .map(new Function<String[], StringBuilder>() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = -3504370368751118677L;

                @Override
                public StringBuilder call(String[] arrayRow) throws Exception {
                    String delayType = null;
                    int departureDelay = AirlineDataUtils.parseMinutes(arrayRow[8], 0);
                    int arrivalDelay = AirlineDataUtils.parseMinutes(arrayRow[9], 0);

                    if(departureDelay >= _delayInMinutes && arrivalDelay >= _delayInMinutes) {
                        delayType = "B";
                    } else if(departureDelay >= _delayInMinutes){
                        delayType = "D";
                    } else if (arrivalDelay >= _delayInMinutes) {
                        delayType = "O";
                    }

                    if(delayType != null) {
                        return AirlineDataUtils.mergeStringArray(arrayRow, ",").append(delayType);
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            })
            .filter(row -> row != null);

    resultRDD.saveAsTextFile(_outputFileName);
    resultRDD.take(10).forEach(System.out :: println);
}
```

**Below is the command I fire -**

```
spark-submit --class com.sanjeevd.sparksimple.airlines.JobRunner 
--master yarn 
--deploy-mode client
--driver-memory=1g
--executor-memory 1g
--executor-cores 1
--num-executors 4
--driver-java-options "$DRIVER_JAVA_OPTS"
--conf spark.yarn.jars=hdfs://sanjeevd.xxx:9000/user/spark/share/lib/*.jar SparkSimple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar select-all-where
```

**The output I get is -**

> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>   10/14/1987,0741,0912,SAN,SFO,447,91,79,11,23B
>   10/15/1987,0729,0903,SAN,SFO,447,94,79,-1,14O
>   10/17/1987,0741,0918,SAN,SFO,447,97,79,11,29B
>   10/19/1987,0749,0922,SAN,SFO,447,93,79,19,33B
>   10/23/1987,0731,0902,SAN,SFO,447,91,79,1,13O
>   10/24/1987,0744,0908,SAN,SFO,447,84,79,14,19B
>   10/26/1987,0735,0904,SAN,SFO,447,89,79,5,15O
>   10/28/1987,0741,0919,SAN,SFO,447,98,90,16,24B
>   10/29/1987,0742,0906,SAN,SFO,447,84,90,17,11B
>   10/01/1987,0936,1035,SFO,RNO,192,59,46,21,34B
>   SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/jars/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>   SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `take(10)` on RDD with just `filter` and `map` transformations, spark will return 10 matching rows from random partition. Spark executes `take` action in lazy way, so it reads one partition and if there less than 10 results, then it probes 4 more, then 20 more, etc, so I assume your code doesn't even touch remaining 21 files on HDFS (you can ensure that looking on SparkUI)

What you are looking for is probably `foreachPartition` action - it executes a function for every partition on driver passing iterable partition content, so you can easily print sample rows.

Comment: Thanks! Actually my code is indeed processing 22 files as I can see 22 partitions in my output folder, but you mentioned an interesting point about 'take'. I thought 'take' is going to work on each partition of RDD which is not the case as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436559/why-apache-spark-take-function-not-parallel. I thoughts 'take' will pull 10 records from each partition which is a wrong assumption clearly. I will try 'foreachPartition' too. Thank you!!!